# Removing items from a collection while iterating through it

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop

Though this question might seem cliched, I have failed to find a proper explanation till now after all the googling that I could do.
This is regarding removing an item from a List while iterating through it. It doest work while iterating the loop forward, while backward looping just works. Here is some sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numberOfIterations = 0;
    var listString = GetData();
    var length = listString.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < listString.Count; i++)
    {
        numberOfIterations++;
        if (ShouldRemove(listString[i]))
        {
            listString.Remove(listString[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of iterations run {0}", numberOfIterations);
    numberOfIterations = 0;
    listString = GetData();
    for (var i = listString.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        numberOfIterations++;
        if (ShouldRemove(listString[i]))
        {
            listString.Remove(listString[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of iterations run {0}", numberOfIterations);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool ShouldRemove(string value)
{
    return (value.StartsWith("A"));
}

private static List<string> GetData()
{
    List<string> retList = new List<string>();
    retList.Add("Apple");
    retList.Add("Banana");
    retList.Add("Aeroplane");
    retList.Add("Cosmos");
    retList.Add("Doggy");
    retList.Add("Adam");
    retList.Add("Crocodile");
    return retList;
}
```

The output is :

```
Number of iterations run 4
Number of iterations run 7
```

I want to understand why is this happening. As I debugged through the code, I found the second condition in the for construct (i < listString.Count, in first case and i >= 0 in the second case) gets reevaluated after every loop. But that may be specific to C# language. Is that the only reason why the loop runs for each element in second case while it runs for just 4 times in first case?
I need an answer from an interview answer perspective. Thanks for reading!

Comment: In your first case, when you remove an element, you still increment the index, so you fail to remove the element that _was_ the next element but is now in the position of the element you just removed. Only half the elements wind up removed in that case. See the marked duplicate for a nearly identical scenario, with the exact same behavior and explanation. All C-descendant languages have this semantic of re-evaluating the entire expression...frankly, it's the only approach that makes sense. It's just an expression...you can't ask the compiler to pick and choose which parts should be invariant.

Comment: I think the reason is pretty logical and straightforward. There is nothing new this compiler is doing or anything special about language also.  for loop condition is based on `i < listString.Count` for the first for loop scenario and list length is kept decreasing after each remove when the condition is met. So after "Apple" and "Aerop.." removal from the list, its size has decreased and when `i` reach that value it comes out of it. But in second case condition is ` i >= 0` which is not changing as per each item removal. I couldn't format it better because question is marked duplicate.